# How do I access methods in React for unit testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, reactjs

I'm having an incredibly difficult time unit testing anything with React. The docs on TestUtils are sparse and there's no examples. Google *seems* to only be giving me a couple results. I'm using Jasmine, but that's not really the part that's giving me grief.

Here's the simplest thing I've tried testing:

```
var BigButton = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <button className="big-submit" data-color={this.props.color} onClick={this.props.action}>{this.props.text}</button>
    );
  },
  foo: function () {},
  bar: function () {
    this.foo();
  }
});
```

I have a test with

```
describe('BigButton', function () {
  describe('render', function () {
    it('creates a button', function () {
      var button = <BigButton />;
      TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(button);
      debugger;
    });
  });
});
```

My question is how do I access anything meaningful in a React class from the outside? How do I even check if render returns a button HTML element? I know how to use testing spies, but how do I even find the method `foo` to spy on and how do I call `bar`? Everything seems to be somehow wrapped up in a way that's completely untestable.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you're aware, but Facebook wrote it's own testing library built upon Jasmine: https://facebook.github.io/jest

They have a tutorial for testing react here: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react.html

I think this is a good example on how to work with TestUtils, even if you don't want to use jest. The main points are:

- `renderIntoDocument()` returns a reference to a detached DOM node
- you use helpers like `findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag()` (see [TestUtils](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html)) to get references to subnodes out of your component
- you can use `getDOMNode()` on your reference for assertions

Comment: Thanks, the first point got me being able to test events and DOM props, but I'm still not sure how to spy on functions. It seems normal Jasmine spying doesn't really work. Says its never called but it's for sure being called. Im guessing its not using the same instance of the function passed to it. Like cloning it or something...

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to spying on component functions?

Comment: Looking for an answer too

Answer (score 3):

to spy on methods, *before* you render the components, you can access the methods object through
`var methods = ComponentName.prototype.__reactAutoBindMap`

then (with jasmine) you can say:
`var methodSpy = spyOn(methods, 'methodName').and.callThrough()`

then you can render the component:
`widget = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(React.createElement(ComponentName, params))`