# Unit test non static methods in React

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, reactjs

I want to write unit tests for methods in a react component. I want to do this without render the component. This because I do not want to set up all the data needed for a full render. I want to do something like this:

```
describe('MyList', function () {
  describe('fooSort', function () {
     it('sort strings', function () {
      var list = <MyList />;

      var result = list.fooSort(['a', 'c', 'b'])
      expect(result).to.be.equal(['a', 'b', 'c'])
    });
  });
});
```

This can be achieved by adding fooSort as a static method, but that will make it impossible for the method to access this. And it also does not feel right.

Is there a way to access the methods or is it an other way to do this kind of testing?

I know this post is similar to: [How do I access methods in React for unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686883/how-do-i-access-methods-in-react-for-unit-testing) but not really the same.

Comment: Why do you not want to use TestUtils from React? That would allow you to render the component and test a method since `TestUtils.renderIntoDocument` will return an instance of your component on which your `fooSort()` would be available.

Comment: Because my render function needs some mandatory props and will fail if they are not passed. So I want to avoid the render method to avoid creating the data needed in the props. But if render is the only way, I'll go for your suggestion.

Comment: Seems like a small price to pay, IMO, generate some proper fixtures and you're set - You'll likely need it later anyways.

Comment: You are probably right, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you use `new MyList` instead of JSX `<MyList />` this would work.

```
describe('MyList', function () {
  describe('fooSort', function () {
     it('sort strings', function () {
      var list = new MyList;

      var result = list.fooSort(['a', 'c', 'b'])
      expect(result).to.be.equal(['a', 'b', 'c'])
    });
  });
});
```

Note being if it's JSX it will be transpiled to `React.createElement(MyList)` which in your case is not what you want.